# How to understand the output of GLMGam and apply the gam.predict to real case?

Tags: statsmodels, glm, gam

I am leraning the GAM model using the [statsmodels package](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.gam.generalized_additive_model.GLMGam.html), and I used the df_autos data model provided by UCI. However, I had a hard time to understand the ouput of the GAM and also failed to use gam.predict to predict a score.

Here is the code I used:

```
from statsmodels.gam.tests.test_penalized import df_autos
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import statsmodels.api as sm


df_autos_new = df_autos[['city_mpg', 'weight','hp']].copy()

# Split the data into X (input features) and y (output variable)
X = df_autos_new.drop(columns='city_mpg')
y = df_autos_new['city_mpg']

# Split the data into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

x_spline = df_autos_new[['weight', 'hp']]

bs = BSplines(x_spline, df=[5, 5], degree=[3, 3])

gam = sm.GLMGam.from_formula('city_mpg ~ weight + hp', data=df_autos_new, smoother=bs).fit()

# Evaluate the GAM
print(gam.summary())
```

And the output is like:
[image]

And I tried to check the output of the model using
`y_pred = gam.predict(df_autos)`
but got the erros like:

```
ValueError: shapes (203,3) and (11,) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 11 (dim 0)
```

So I was wondering what's the input data format? And how to understand the output of the  Generalized Linear Model Regression Results ?

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: (1) `statsmodels` looks like a Python package, not an R package. Maybe edit the tags for your question?  (2) `glm-math` doesn't look like a tag you want (3) whenever possible, it's best to post output in textual format (cut and paste) rather than as an image ...

Comment: show (at least) the last part of the traceback, so we can see where the error is raised. predict also need `exog_smooth` with values for the spline(s). https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.gam.generalized_additive_model.GLMGamResults.predict.html